# cluster one-dimensional data using pvclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dimension, statistics-bootstrap, pvclust

Thanks for taking time read this question. I have some one-dimensional data to cluster in R. The basic `hclust` command works fine. But the `pvclust` command, however, does not take one-dimensional data, and keeps saying:

```
Error in hclust(distance, method = method.hclust) : 
  must have n >= 2 objects to cluster
```

I found a work-around, that I added some all-zero rows to the data. So the data becomes:

```
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  [,4]  [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
[1,]  7.424 14.251 15.957 1.542 2.451 20.836 13.534 20.003 12.555 10.817
[2,]      0      0      0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]      0      0      0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0
[4,]      0      0      0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Then I ran `pvclust`, and it worked!

But I am concerned that this work-around screws up the mathematics laying behind pvclust. Can any one tell me whether I am right/wrong, and if there's a better solution to my question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me state that **none of these methods is meant for one-dimensional data**.

For one-dimensional data, please use a method that exploits that the data can be *sorted*. For example, use a method based on kernel density estimation.

The term "cluster analysis" is usually used with *multidimensional data only*. In one dimensional, there are much better methods. See also "natural breaks optimization", but IMHO you should be using kernel density estimation: split the data at local minima in the KDE.

Now to your actual question. Most likely the problem is that you are ... passing 1 dimensional data. Which is interpreted as **one record, with `d` dimensions**, and thus the method complains about having a single sample only. You may have success by first **transposing** your record.

With your hack of adding zero records, the result most likely becomes bogus. You are probably clustering a data set that has 1 vector that contains your data, and 3 vectors that are all zero...

But in the end, you *should not be using these methods here anyway*! Use a method that exploits that your data can be sorted.

Comment: By the way, do you also know the answer to this question: suppose I used **kernel density estimation**, and make a cut a the local minima. Then can I test how significant the left peak is separated from the right peak? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using KDE a lot - I work with multidimensional data only. So I don't know references for suitable significance tests. You need to consider what your Hypothesis is: uniform distribution? Then you could probably use K-S testing. For such questions, have a look at the stats.stackexchange.com sister site, it's *much* more appropriate for statistics questions.